# Having some trouble with passing a array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hi im new to coding anyway my professor assigned us a problem which im a little confused over. I keep getting "error: unreachable statement `RainFall ds = new RainFall(months);`". Right now my code is unfinished and it might not make any sense I kept making it worse as I tried to correct it so I apologize in advance. anyway here is the problem and the code

Write A Rainfall class that stores the total rainfall for each of 12 months into an array of doubles. The program should have methods that return the following:

The total rainfall for the year
The average monthly rainfall
The month with most rain
The month with least rain

Ask the user to input 12 values in your main. Write a mutator method in the Rainfall class to add values to your array of doubles. Your main should call the methods of your Rainfall class to get and display the total/average/most/least. 
Demonstrate the class in a complete program. (Do not accept negative numbers for monthly rainfall figures)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hw5pr1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner rain = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] months = new double[12];
        for (int a = 0; 0<12; a++)
        {
            months[a]=rain.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(months[a]);
        }
        RainFall ds = new RainFall(months);
    }   
}


public class RainFall
{
    private double month;
    private double[] months1;
    private double average;
    private double largest;
    private double smallest;

    public RainFall(double[] months)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<12; b++)
        {
            months[b]=months1[b];
        }
    }


   public double total()
   {
        for (int a=0; a<11; a++)
        {
             double month = months1[a]+month;

        }
        return month;
   }
   public double average()
   {
        average=month/12;
        return average;
   }
   public double largest()
   {
       double largest = months1[0];
       for (int a=0; a<1; a++)
       {
           if (months1[a]>largest)
           {
               largest = months1[a];
           }
       }
   }
   public double smallest()
   {
       double smallest = months1[0];
       for (int a=0; a<1; a++)
       {
            if (months1[a]<smallest)
            {
                smallest = months1[a];
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you've got an infinite loop:

```
//              vvvvvv
for (int a = 0; 0 < 12; a++)
{
}
RainFall ds = new RainFall(months);
```

The compiler is able to determine `0 < 12` will always be true. The loop will never terminate so anything after it is unreachable. I guess you meant `a < 12`.

Comment: Thanks! Ha cant believed I missed that I have everything working now.